# NSString being set but appears empty when calling from another class - iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, nsstring, get

I have a small piece of code that sets the NSString (*strUsername*) of the class **Username** to the value which is typed into a UITextField and then a button is pressed. This works fine:
**UsernameViewController.m**

```
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
    #import "Username.h"

    @interface UsernameViewController : UIViewController
    {
        Username *username;
        __weak IBOutlet UITextField *test;
    }

    @property (nonatomic, retain)IBOutlet UITextField *txtUsername;
    @property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField *test;

    -(IBAction)setUsername;

    @end

#import "UsernameViewController.h"
#import "Username.h"

@implementation UsernameViewController

@synthesize test=_test;    
    - (void)viewDidLoad
        {
            [super viewDidLoad];
            username = [[Username alloc] init];
        }

        -(IBAction)setUsername
        {
            NSString *inputUsername = self.test.text;
            NSLog(@"inputUsername is: %@", inputUsername);

            username.strUsername = inputUsername;
            NSLog(@"the username.strUsername is now: %@", username.strUsername);
        }
```

My NSLog output shows that the UItextfield input and NSString setter are working:

```
LocNews1[6699:707] inputUsername is: Harry brown 
LocNews1[6699:707] the username.strUsername is now: Harry brown
```

Now when it hit the back button on this view it return me back to a UITableViewController. I then perform a pull down to refresh action and its called the following method:

**TestViewController.m (UITableViewController type)**

```
#import "TestViewController.h"
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "DetailViewController.h"
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "NewsArticle.h"
#import "ResultsCustomCell.h"
#import "XMLParser.h"

@implementation TestViewController

//some code

- (void)addItem 
{
    username = [[Username alloc] init];

    // Use XMLparser to check for updated new feeds.
    if(username.strUsername != NULL)
    {
        NSLog(@"ViewController username.strUsername is:%@",username.strUsername);
        activeUsername = username.strUsername;
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"%@",username.strUsername);
        activeUsername = @"";
    }

    NSString *myLat = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%f", locationManager.location.coordinate.latitude];
    NSString *mylong = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%f", locationManager.location.coordinate.longitude];
    XMLParser *parseQuestionnaire = [[XMLParser alloc] init];
    NSLog(@"username %@",activeUsername);
    newsArticle = [parseQuestionnaire parseXML:myLat:mylong:activeUsername];   

    [self.tableView reloadData];

    [self stopLoading];
}
```

However this shows the NSLog output as:

```
LocNews1[6699:707] ViewController username.strUsername is:
```

As you can see the string has been set in UsernameViewController.m but when I try and call the string back in TestViewController.m is appears to be blank (there is no null in the NSLog, just blank);

What could be causing this?

**EDIT: Username.h/m**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Username : NSObject
{
    NSString *strUsername;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *strUsername;

@end

#import "Username.h"

@implementation Username

@synthesize strUsername;

-(id)init
{
    strUsername = [[NSString alloc] init];
    return self;   
}

@end
```

Note: Username is declared in both TestViewController.h and UsernameViewController.h like: Username *username;

Comment: Where is `username` declared? Is it an instance variable? Global variable?

Comment: Code has been update to show the Username Class and its declaration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `username` instance variable in that instance of UsernameViewController is completely unrelated to the `username` instance variable in the instance of TestViewController. You'll need to store the variable in a place that both controllers know about or pass it between them if you want them both to have access. Simply having two variables with the same name doesn't connect them in any way.

Comment: I have tried passing the value from UsernameViewController to the Parent view controller (TestViewController) using `TestViewController *testViewController = [[TestViewController alloc]init];
    //self.test.text = [(testViewController *)self.navigationController.presentingViewController].text;
    testViewController.activeUsername = test.text;` in the IBAction method.
However when returning to TestViewController using the back button in the UINavController the string `activeUsername` is null. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The TestViewController you create there is not the same one that's actually controlling the view. Just like different instances of NSString hold different text, each instance of TestViewController is its own object with its own variables.